# Android thread stime,utime?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

What does this mean and what's the difference?

`stime` and `utime` in `DDMS`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**utime -** cumulative time spent executing user code, in "jiffies" (usually 10ms). Only available under Linux.
**stime -** cumulative time spent executing system code, in "jiffies" (usually 10ms).

Please more detail check link http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html